# The best way to run function on each page

Tags: python, django

I have one question, namely, what is the best way to run any function on each python application in the project?
For example, I have 1 project - bbCms which contains 2 apps - articles and board. 
And I would like to run function doSomething on each page of these apps. 
On PHP I can create file, e.g. functions.php, type code and inside each app by require run this function.

How can I solve this problem in Python (django)?

Comment: We need more information. let us see your `views.py` at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NOTE: Please update your code at lease `views.py` to know how your project works.

First, django process your requests with `views.py`.

if you use `Function based View`, you can simply do with this:

```
def doSomething():
    # do Something
    return something

def index(request):
    doSomething() # add this for all views functions
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

or you can make your own `middleware.py`:

```
def simple_middleware(get_response):
    # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def middleware(request):
        # Change here!! this code will be executed for all requests

        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        response = get_response(request)

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.

        return response

    return middleware
```

and add to `settings.py`:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'myproject.middleware.simple_middware', # add this!
]
```

> REF: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/

Comment: Great, works perfectly.